# Is there any way to view older stdout in zsh (or anything else)?

Tags: shell, zsh, macos, stdout

I ran a command today that:

- printed some stdout text
- that stdout is no longer viewable by scrolling through the shell (because zsh's scrolling stops)

Is there some way to access that output? Unfortunately, I cannot get that same output from re-running the command.

Comment: It's not zsh that scrolls. It's your terminal emulator!

Comment: Ah, yes. And I'm using VS Code to do this. I just found a setting in VS Code that allows me to choose the maximum number of lines the terminal keeps in its buffer. It was set to 1000. Seems like setting it to a larger number will only affect the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not zsh that scrolls. It's your terminal emulator!

And it needs to keep previous output around to allow for that scrolling. Once it discards parts of that, they are gone, and you can't bring them back.